# Do I need a dlc to play online?

Tags: diablo-iii, ps4

How to play Diablo-3 Online PS4

I just got Diablo 3 Eternal Collection for PS4, but I can't figure out how to play online or connect to battle.net Are there dlcs or
instructions for this anywhere?

Answer (score 2):

Eternal Collection is the most complete version available on PS4, it already includes all DLCs.

For online play you need to have an active PS+ subscription.